# Configuration File in .net

Tags: c#, configuration, default

We have scheduler developed in .net and it is working fine. We have stored Email Details in application configuration required to send email to support group. It is working fine.

Now my problem is if i add new details in `Application Configuratio`n file or if i update any details in application file and during that operation if i do something wrong i got error saying

```
 Configuration System Failed to initialise.
```

In this scenario email details not found from the configuration system and we wont be able to get email alerts.

Can anyone has any work around for this?

I dont want to use Registry or Machine.config file for some policy reasons.

Comment: What details are you adding? How are you adding  those - manually or through code?

Comment: I am adding/updating settings menually

Comment: You need to provide more details about your config file, how it is being written to and what is this job that you speak of.

Answer (score 0):

You will always get that error if the format of the config file is wrong.  Basically it is the framework saying that you have made a mistake in the layout of the contents of the file.

If you want to post up the contents of the file I might be able to help more.

Comment: Yes that i know and once i get the error i can see the file and find out the error but my point is as we have error scheduler not even get the basic email addresses to send email...

Comment: so i need to check if job run successfully or failed and not be informed by scheduler using email

Comment: Have you got a database the scheduler uses?  I would always store email addresses in a DB in preference to config file.